# Access class variable using Interface type

Tags: java, oop, interface

I've following class

```
class MyClass implements Intrfc {

String pickmeUp = "Its Me";

public static void main(String[] args){

Intrfc ob = new MyClass();
ob.pickmeUp;  ---> How can I access this way ?

  }

}
```

Is there any way to access class variable using Interface type ?

Comment: Unrelated: always use meaningful names, even in examples. And names that you can pronounce. `Intrfc` violates both of those properties ... so just call it MyInterface, or MyExampleInterface.

Comment: Assuming you're happy to use encapsulation and have control over the interface... Read access: declare a getter in the interface, implement it in the class by returning your field. Write access: declare a setter in the interface, implement it in the class by setting your field. Use the setter/getter to access/change the value of [your field / whatever] when referencing an object implementing that interface.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way to access class variable using Interface type ?

No. That is the whole point of an interface.

And yes, interfaces only give you *behavior* (methods), not "state" (variables/fields). That is how things are in Java.

Of course, you can always use `instanceof` to check if the *actual* object is of some more specific type, to then **cast** to that type. But as said, that *defeats* the purpose of using interfaces!

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't access the class variable using interface type, but the interface can define method that can access to the variable.

```
interface Intrfc {

    public String getPickmeUp();

}


class MyClass implements Intrfc {

    String pickmeUp = "Its Me";

    public String getPickmeUp(){
        return pickmeUp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Intrfc ob = new MyClass();
        ob.getPickmeUp();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this definition:

```
class MyClass implements Intrfc {
    String pickmeUp = "Its Me";
}
```

the field `pickmeUp` is not even a member of `Intrfc` interface, so there is no possibility to reach for it using just the interface. `pickmeUp` is a member of a concrete class - `MyClass`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the method of a class using the object of an interface you can do it as follows:

```
//Interface:
public interface TestOne {  
    int a = 5;
    void test();    
    static void testOne(){      
        System.out.println("Great!!!");

    }

    default void testTwo(){

        System.out.println("Wow!!!");

    }
}
//-------------------
//Class implementing it:
package SP;
public class TestInterfacesImp implements Test1, TestOne{   
    @Override
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("I Love java");      
    }

        public void testM() {
            System.out.println("I Love java too");
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestOne.testOne();      
        TestOne obj = new TestInterfacesImp();
        obj.testTwo();
        TestInterfacesImp objImp = new TestInterfacesImp();
        objImp.test();
        ((TestInterfacesImp) obj).testM(); //Here casting is done we have casted to class type


    }
}
```

Hope this helps...